# How can I fix this question about the enforcement of superpower bans?

Tags: support, specific-question

Yesterday I posted a question to the worldbuilding stackexchange asking for help working out how a law banning the possession of certain supernatural abilities (which are granted on a weekly basis and can be voluntarily given up) could be enforced with minimal violation of civil rights. The question can be found [Here.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/120530/how-could-power-control-laws-be-enforced-with-the-fewest-violations-of-civil-l)

It was apparently closed as "primarily opinion based", which as I understand it means that the answer to the question is mostly a matter of personal opinion and there is no knowledge or expertise that would be relevant to giving an accepted answer. I'm confused as to how this applies here, as a good answer to the question would involve knowledge about law and law enforcement. I didn't receive a single comment that explained any problems with it, it was just voted primarily opinion based. What did I do wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

When a question is closed as primarily opinion based, it means that it lacks the possibility of having an objective metric to evaluate all the answers.

In your case,

> a workable method to enforce a law

is a rather weak metric.

One option for you is to make clear what are the criteria that you will use to evaluate the answers.

Comment: What would you propose as an example?

Comment: I understood "as unobtrusive of a way as possible with the fewest violations of civil liberties" to be the metric.

Comment: @user49446 so violating one major civil liberty like the the right for abortion is  objectively better than violating two minor ones such as the right to own a gun and the right to use drugs, just due to the raw amount of civil liberties violated?